# Convert TF Object Detection API model to TFLite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflite

Please help in following iam really stuck when I converting with
following code

```
!python models/research/object_detection/export_tflite_graph_tf2.py \
    --trained_checkpoint_dir {'/content/drive/MyDrive/customTF2/training'} \
    --output_directory {'/content/drive/MyDrive/customTF2/tflite'} \
    --pipeline_config_path {'/content/drive/MyDrive/customTF2/data/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.config'}
```

I get this error

```
File "models/research/object_detection/export_tflite_graph_tf2.py", line 99, in <module>
    from google3.image.understanding.object_detection.input_readers import input_reader_google_pb2   #pylint: disable=unused-import
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google3'
```

Comment: error may suggest that you have to install module `google3`

Comment: Repo `tensorflow/models`: [import google3？How to install google3？this is in "models/research/slim/nets/nasnet/nasnet\_utils.py" · Issue #2576 · tensorflow/models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2576)

Comment: how we install this module? google3 or is this problem in protobuf version?cant install using !pip install google3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/commit/ecdab2324c65504ab52986e2bb5b64edda38f19e
The update is not ok. Reports have been made.
Try to comment out line 99 it did work for me